# Best approach to query nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have around 10k-15k nodes of different types (with different node properties) and around 1m relationships (with properties). I wish to ask that what is best approach for querying the nodes using where condition. I have already tested:

- a) Defining the properties on `node[0]`.
- b) Auto-index which require pre-indexing of all the nodes.

Can somebody succinctly specify the to-dos (please avoid links to `Neo4j`  as I have those)?

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you must know what exactly you want to query for, and give us more info of your graph and relationships, try creating a sample of your graph using [Neo4j Console](http://console.neo4j.org/), and so we can help you.. As you said, you didn't need link..

Comment: Querying is for retrieving data from nodes with their node properties or relationships and/or relationship properties (analogues to SQL queries). On Neo4j cypher was suggested but it need indices for querying based on node properties - auto_index is an option but it requires to be created before any node. Moreover for auto_index modifications are required in properties file. So I am lost what to use?

Comment: With Neo4j 2.0, you can use Labels and indexing that is transparent and possible even after the data creation, http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-schema-index.html